# hash password on create and update

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to hash a password for users when the record is created and when the user updates their password. On creation, I can do something like

```
User.beforeCreate((user, options) => {
  user.password = encryptPassword(user.password)
})
```

Which will be easily executed and hash the password for new users. But I have an issue when updating the password. If I just do

```
User.beforeUpdate((user, options) => {
  user.password = encryptPassword(user.password)
})
```

then everytime users updating their record (i.e update name, address, etc) it triggers the hook and re-hash the password.

How can I tell when the password is changed so that I can trigger the hook? Also instead of having those 2 hooks, how can I just use `beforeSave` to achieve the same result?

**UPDATE**

As per requested my User definition is as simple as

```
sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    id: {
      type:          Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey:    true,
    },
    emailAddress: {
      field:        'email_address',
      type:         Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull:    false,
      unique:       true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: {
          args:     true,
          msg:      "Email is not valid"
        }
      },
    },
    password: {
      type:         Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull:    false,
      validate: {
        min: {
          args:     6,
          msg:      "Password must be more than 6 characters"
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey there let me give this a shot

So first off you can run the same function for both hooks similar to below:

```
function encryptPasswordIfChanged(user, options) {
  if (user.changed('password')) {
    encryptPassword(user.get('password'));
  }
}

User.beforeCreate(encryptPasswordIfChanged);
User.beforeUpdate(encryptPasswordIfChanged);
```

When you want to change the password in your update and create API endpoints, you can just call `user.set('password', somePasswordString);`.  I'm not exactly sure if that is exactly what you need but I think this pattern should do what you need.  The `.changed` function should return `true` when you are creating the user because the `_previousDataValues` for the password should be `undefined`.

Good luck :)

Comment: Hey that looks alright. With `.changed()` I can tell when the password is changed. But another issue is the hook does not trigger validation. So if my validation says minimum password is 6 characters, I can still pass 3 digits password.

Comment: Did you check https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/hooks/ ?  It implies that the validation hook would run before those two hooks.  I may be able to give you some insight if you post your Sequelize definition for the user table you're working on.

Comment: I understand with the hook order and it is still relevant with v4 I am using http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html#order-of-operations. But I still don't understand why the validation is not applied when update/create hook is triggered. I have added my User definition.